# getAttribute() and javascript executor not return actual display value

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to return my passed data from the text box but when i try to return value from the text box it does not return actual value. There is on condition text box automatically converts the first later into capital. Suppose when i passed value "abc" then text box shows "Abc" but when get that value by using getAttribute() or javascript executor it returns me "abc" instead of "Abc".

```
String input= "abc";

element.sendKeys(input);

//text box shows "Abc"

Thread.sleep(2000);

String output=element.getAttribute("value");

System.out.println("output");
```

output is "abc" insted of "Abc"

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches that you can try:

Use innerHTML attribute:

```
String output=element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Select the value and copy to clipboard:

```
element.Click();
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a"));
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"c"));
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
String output = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

Comment: both the methods i used but for parallel running clipboard method not work.